# Can I render to an offline context in a web worker?

Tags: web-audio-api

I want to render audio into an offline audio context using the web audio API, but I don't want doing so to block user interactions on the main UI thread.

Can I somehow render my audio graph in a web worker? I don't think I can pass an offline context to the worker because the offline context can't be serialized like a primitive javascript object.

Answer (score 2):

The OfflineAudioContext actually does its rendering in a separate thread (in Chrome, at least).  So you don't need to do this manually.

If you DID want to do it manually, you'd need for OfflineAudioContext to be supported in Worker threads, and it isn't yet.

Comment: Hello Chris.  This still seems to be missing.  Is this tracked somewhere that I can follow?  Thanks, as always, for your efforts!

Comment: It's an issue in the Web Audio API github: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1098.  Again, you don't need this for this use case - OfflineAudioContext already works asynchronously, on a separate thread.